# Using anchor tags inside reactstrap popover body is not working

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I am trying to create a popover that will show a list of links.

The popover is launched using focus

```
<FaBug id="PopoverFocus" title="Click to view Bugs details" />
<UncontrolledPopover trigger="focus" placement="right" target="PopoverFocus">
  <PopoverBody>
     <li key={i}> <u><a href={ bugidurl } target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{bugid}</a></u>  </li>
     <li key={i}> <u><a href={ bugidurl } target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{bugid}</a></u>  </li>
     <li key={i}> <u><a href={ bugidurl } target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{bugid}</a></u>  </li>
  </PopoverBody>
</UncontrolledPopover>
```

Now that popover is seen with a list of links, I am unable to navigate to the links after clicking on it. It is just closing the popover.

Comment: I had to use trigger="legacy" to achieve it.